# Should the top-level `name` property in `compose.yaml` set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` for the purpose of interpolation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have a `compose.yaml` file like the following:

```yaml
name: my-project
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_database
```

I would expect my `docker compose config` output to look like this:

```yaml
name: my-project
services:
  database:
    container_name: my-project_database
    image: postgres:10
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: my-project_default
```

But it doesn't. It looks like this:

```yaml
name: my-project
services:
  database:
    container_name: _database
    image: postgres:10
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: my-project_default
```

The `${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}` in `container_name` isn't interpolated. At first glance, this seems to make sense, since you'd expect that syntax to be only for pulling in environment variables. But the [Compose spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element) says this:

> Whenever project name is defined by top-level `name` or by some custom mechanism, it MUST be exposed for interpolation and environment variable resolution as `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`

So then am I just missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm running docker version 20.10.16, which I think is the current release, and `docker compose` doesn't even support a top-level `name` element. Trying to `docker compose up` with your example `compose.yaml` results in `(root) Additional property name is not allowed`.

Comment: You must be using an outdated version of Docker Compose. I'm on v2.5.1 and the top-level `name` property works fine outside of the interpolation use case. See the [Compose spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element). The top-level `name` property is fully supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug. See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9530.

So the answer is **yes**, the top-level `name` property in `compose.yaml` **should** set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` for the purpose of interpolation.